# Nattable sort on button click, placed on column header

Tags: nattable

**GIVEN**:
I have a nattable with sort enabled.

**TODO**:
1) Instead of UP/DOWN black triangles which appear on column header i want buttons with same images to appear
2) I also want sort to happen when i click on these buttons

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**:
I tried using a SortIconPainter but, i can set only custom images in this. I have no idea how to get buttons on column header.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have buttons in table cells. It is a custom rendered table and not a widget container. You can pass images that look like buttons and register an `IMouseAction` with an `IMouseEventMatcher` that checks for the painter and the image. Not a trivial task.

You can have a look at the `ButtonCellPainter` and whether it is possible to combine it with another painter in a `CellPainterDecorator`. Actually I am not a big fan of that painter as it uses a lot of asynchronous code for the pseudo animation. But maybe it suits your needs.

Comment: Hi Dirk, Will try out the 1st approach you suggested.

Comment: Following worked: Added an image using **ImagePainter** and then listened for mouse click event. Triggered sort if the click is on the image.